# How to calculate RMS from flutter sound recorder

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I'm using flutter sound recorder to capture some audio and i have set up my recorder as such:

```
await myRecorder.startRecorder(
   toStream: recordingDataController.sink,
   codec: Codec.pcm16,
   numChannels: 1,
   sampleRate: 16000,
);
```

I'm trying to calculate the volume in real time so i have set up a StreamController and a function that calculates the RMS for a given interval of samples

```
recordingDataController.stream.listen((buffer) => {bufferToBufferData(buffer)});

void bufferToBufferData(FoodData buffer) {
  rawRecordingData.addAll(buffer.data.buffer.asInt16List());
  _calculateVolume();
}

// Calculate RMS for certain interval of samples
void _calculateVolume({int interval = 800}) {
  for (int i = volume.length + 1; i < rawRecordingData.length ~/ interval; i++) {
    double sumOfSquares = 0;
    for (var element in rawRecordingData.sublist(i * interval, i * interval + interval)) {
      sumOfSquares += pow(element / 32767, 2);
    }
    double meanSquare = sumOfSquares / interval;
    double rms = sqrt(meanSquare);
    volume.add(rms);
  }
}
```

But the calculated RMS doesn't look right, when I try pass the raw data to FFmpegKit and convert it to WAV and then back to the original raw data the RMS looks correct.

```
  // Raw recording data is Int16List from buffer and gives me the 'wrong' RMS
  Uint8List list = Uint8List.fromList(rawRecordingData);
  File file = File('$path/raw.bytes');
  await file.create();
  file.writeAsBytesSync(list);
  await FFmpegKit.execute('-f s16le -ar 16000 -i ${file.path} -y $path/rawtowav.wav');

  await FFmpegKit.execute('-i $path/rawtowav.wav -f s16le -ar 16000 $path/data.bytes');
  file = File('$path/data.bytes');
  // This gives me a better RMS from the looks of it
  List<int> test = file.readAsBytesSync().buffer.asInt16List();
```

The RMS data before passing through FFmpegKit looks like it has a lot of white noise or something you cant exactly see a difference beetwen silence and talking but after the WAV conversion i can perfectly see a difference between silence and talking

So my question is, am I capturing the data from recorder wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

As I assumed I was interpreting the data from the mic in a wrong way. Flutter sound recorder is returning Uint8List but the data is being sampled with 16-bit signed int (I don't know why isn't the mic returning a Int16List more on that topic: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/issues/596)) the main problem was when I tried to parse the Uint8List to Int16List in this line

```
rawRecordingData.addAll(buffer.data.buffer.asInt16List());
```

I just parsed one small buffer part of the mics output so I got some data loss (sometimes the buffer data in bytes isn't even divisible by two so you can't get a 2 byte number from it) I solved the problem by adding this line to **_calculateVolume** function

```
List<int> rawData = Int16List.view(Uint8List.fromList(rawRecordingData).buffer);
```

Which takes the bytes from rawRecordingData as a whole and then with the **Int16List.view()** function interprets the bytes as a signed 16-bit integers.